# Golly Python Error: Weird syntax error "list has no attribute g"

Tags: python, conways-game-of-life

I have the following piece of code in Golly's Scripts folder, but it returns me an attribute error, which I can't find out why happens *****.

If you understand Game of Life: it should put induction coils automatically near a selected unstable pattern, but this is just a prototype.

```
import golly as g
import random as r

coilsinp = g.getstring('Python list of induction coils to use?', '', 'Induction coils')
layerinp = g.getstring('Maximum number of induction coils inducting each other?')
mcoilinp = g.getstring('Maximum number of induction coils?')

if coilsinp == '':
   coillist = [g.parse('2o$2o!'), g.parse('bo$obo$bo!'), g.parse('b2o$o2bo$bobo$2bo!'). g.parse('b3o$o2bo$bobo$2bo!'). g.parse('3o$o2bo$b2o!'), g.parse('3o$o2bo$2b2o!')]
else:
   coillist = coilsinp.split(',')

if layerinp != '':
   maxlayers = layerinp
else:
   maxlayers = 3

if mcoilinp != '':
   maxcoils = mcoilinp
else:
   maxcoils = 12

dpa = (maxcoils - r.randint(0, maxcoils))
tosel = g.getcells(g.getselrect)
dasel = g.getselrect
g.addlayer()
g.putcells(tosel, 0, 0)
g.select(0, 0, dasel[2], dasel[3])
while true:

   while dpa > 0:
      g.putcells(coilsinp[r.randint(0, 5)], r.randint(-11, (dasel[2] + 11), r.randint(-11, (dasel[3] + 11))
      dpa -= 1

   if g.getselrect == g.evolve(g.getcells(g.getselrect), 50):
      break
```

And the traceback points me to line 9.

***** At time of editing, I already found out. I'm just clarifying what the topic was.

Comment: Can you show the actual error and traceback?

Comment: What do you mean, "somewhere"? The error will tell you the exact line number and its contents.

Comment: `line 9, in <module>
      coillist =     [g.parse('2o$2o!'),g.parse('bo$obo$bo!'),g.parse('b2o$o2bo$bobo$2bo !'),g.parse('b3o$o2bo$bobo$2bo!'),g.parse('3o$o2bo$b2o!',g.parse(3o     $o2bo$2b2o!')]
    AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'g'`

Comment: That says `AttributeError`, not `SyntaxError`.

Comment: And the last `g.parse` call in that traceback is missing a `'` for its string argument, but it's present in the code in your question. Can you post the exact code and traceback?

Comment: It is difficult to copy it exactly as the traceback appears in a unselectable pop-up window (the script is loaded from the program Golly).

Comment: Why are you guys downvoting? I am a poor person who can't fix a problem!

Comment: You're getting down-voted for not following the posting guidelines.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the source code, line 9, between the 3rd, 4th, and 5th list elements.  You separated with a period instead of a comma, giving you a long element of

```
g.parse('b2o$o2bo$bobo$2bo!'). g.parse('b3o$o2bo$bobo$2bo!'). g.parse('3o$o2bo$b2o!')
```

The parser burfed at `g.parse('b2o$o2bo$bobo$2bo!'). g`, since the parser's return doesn't have any attribute named "g" (the one just after the parentheses).

Does that get you moving?